# Can a SizedBox width be increased in both left and right direction?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

In my code when i increase the width of a SizedBox, the width always increases to right side. What i am looking for is, if we can increase the width to left side as well as right side.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollController: MyInfiniteScrollController(negative:true),
    axis: Axis.horizontal,
    child: CustomPainter(
      painter: MyCustomPainter(model: MyNotifierModel()),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 250,
        width: myDynamicWidthBaseOnScrollAndSetState)
    )
)
```

I am aware of the infinite_listview to achieve this. But i am trying to use a single CustomPainter and SizedBox instead of having a list of CustomPainter.

Comment: you can increse hight and width of SizedBox .